# Restoring iptables at boot (rc.local)

Tags: iptables, restore, rules, rc.local, fedora-22

I have saved my iptables rules using the `iptables-save >` command and i am trying to restore these rules when the machine boots up. I have added the command `iptables-restore < "path to rules file"` in the `rc.local` but it doesn't fire up the rules.

I tried directly running the command in the terminal and it worked, so i know there is nothing wrong with the command. I have made the `rc.local` file executable as well with the command 
`sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local`.

What might be the problem ?

Edit - am using fedora 22

Comment: F22 uses firewalld and sytemd - it's time to embrace the change and move on from plain iptables and rc files.

Comment: And hopefully people can tell from my answer how much I love being forced to do that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm afraid time has moved on, and F22 is one of those cherishable distros using the adorable new `systemd` to start things up.  One of the many happy enjoyable side effects is that `rc.local` is no longer run (or to be more precise, I haven't been able to make it run reliably) so that won't be helping.

Put your firewall rules into `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` in the normal way, using `iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables`, clear your rules, then do `systemctl start iptables.service` to apply them.  If `iptables -L -n -v` confirms they've taken, do `systemctl enable iptables.service` to start them at boot time.

Comment: Executing `/etc/rc.local` is simply disabled by default because of some unknown `systemd` ideology. Just run `systemctl enable --now rc-local` to permanently enable it and immediately execute the commands in the file.

Answer (score 0):

check if iptables is started on boot, chkconfig --list iptables